# Trouble migrating data from old tables to a new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I want to replace with a new one. The old tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OldContacts](
    [OldContactID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NULL,
    [BusinessID] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [JobTitle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Telephone] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DecisionMaker] [int] NULL,
    [PrimaryContact] [int] NULL,
    [ContactDisabled] [int] NULL,
    [ZoomInfoPersonId] [int] NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [BusinessListRecordID] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction](
    [TransactionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreditTransactionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContactEmail] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ContactPhone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactJobTitle] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [EmailBought] [bit] NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [AddressLine3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Town] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Telephone] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Website] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Industry] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [BusinessID] [int] NULL)
```

And the new one:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientContacts](
    [ClientContactID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientUserID] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [BusinessID] [int] NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ContactFirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactSurname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactEmail] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactPhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactMobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactJobTitle] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmailBought] [bit] NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AddressLine3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Town] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CompanyTelephone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CompanyWebsite] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Industry] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DecisionMaker] [bit] NULL,
    [PrimaryContact] [bit] NULL,
    [ContactDisabled] [bit] NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [BusinessListRecordID] [int] NULL,
    [IsPurchased] [bit] NULL
)
```

The old logic was, you created a record on `Transaction`, and it would then add a record to `OldContacts`, creating the redundancy we are now trying to get rid of.
However, you could have a record on `OldContacts` that didn't come from a `Transaction`.

Now, I need to migrate the data to the new table, getting all the `Transaction` records plus the `OldContacts` that aren't duplicates of the `Transaction` ones. And here is what I've got so far:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ClientContacts
        (
            ClientUserID, PersonID, BusinessID, CompanyID, CompanyName, ContactName,
            ContactFirstName, ContactSurname, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, ContactMobile,
            ContactJobTitle, EmailBought, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3,
            County, Town, Country, CompanyTelephone, CompanyWebsite, Industry,
            DecisionMaker, PrimaryContact, ContactDisabled, CreationDate,
            BusinessListRecordID, IsPurchased
        )
        SELECT
            CT.ClientUserId,
            LC.ZIPersonId,
            LC.BusinessID,
            T.CompanyId,
            T.CompanyName,
            CONCAT(LC.FirstName, ' ', LC.Surname),
            LC.FirstName,
            LC.Surname,
            LC.EmailAddress,
            LC.Telephone AS ContactPhone,
            LC.Mobile AS ContactMobile,
            LC.JobTitle,
            T.EmailBought,
            T.AddressLine1,     
            T.AddressLine2,
            T.AddressLine3,
            T.County,
            T.Town,
            T.Country,
            T.Telephone,
            T.Website,
            T.Industry,
            LC.DecisionMaker,
            LC.PrimaryContact,
            LC.ContactDisabled,
            LC.CreationDate,
            LC.BusinessListRecordID,
            CASE LC.ZIPersonId WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM OldContacts LC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Transaction] T ON LC.ZIPersonId = T.PersonId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CreditTransaction CT ON T.CreditTransactionId = CT.CreditTransactionId
```

However, this only gets me one record, where the ZIPersonId matches. How can I get the records from both tables without getting duplicates?

Here are some test records:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OldContacts (ClientID, BusinessID, Title, FirstName, Surname, JobTitle, EmailAddress, Telephone, Mobile, DecisionMaker, PrimaryContact, ContactDisabled, ZIPPersonId, CreationDate, BusinessListRecordID)
VALUES
(13832, 10, 'Mr', 'John55', 'Smith55', 'Admin', 'john55@smith.com', '123456', '123456', 0, 0, 0, 55, GETDATE(), NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.OldContacts (ClientID, BusinessID, Title, FirstName, Surname, JobTitle, EmailAddress, Telephone, Mobile, DecisionMaker, PrimaryContact, ContactDisabled, ZIPPersonId, CreationDate, BusinessListRecordID)
VALUES
(13832, 10, 'Mr', 'John66', 'Smith66', 'Admin', 'john66@smith.com', '123456', '123456', 0, 0, 0, 66, GETDATE(), NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.OldContacts (ClientID, BusinessID, Title, FirstName, Surname, JobTitle, EmailAddress, Telephone, Mobile, DecisionMaker, PrimaryContact, ContactDisabled, ZIPPersonId, CreationDate, BusinessListRecordID)
VALUES
(13832, 10, 'Mr', 'John77', 'Smith77', 'Admin', 'john77@smith.com', '123456', '123456', 0, 0, 0, 77, GETDATE(), NULL)

-- ******************************************************************************

INSERT INTO dbo.[Transaction] (CreditTransactionId, PersonId, CompanyId, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactJobTitle, EmailBought, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, County, Town, Country, Telephone, Website, Industry, BusinessID)
VALUES
(7965, 77, 123, 'TestCompany', 'John77 Smith77', 'john77@smith77.com', 'Admin', 1, 'AL1','AL2', 'AL3', 'testcounty', 'testtown', 'testcountry', '321456', 'www.test.com', 'someIndustry', 10)
```

**EDIT**

I replaced both joins with LEFT OUTER JOINS and I now have all the records. However, I am not getting some columns: no ClientUserId, CompanyId, CompanyName  for contacts that come from the `OldContacts` table and the isPurchased field is always one, when it shouldn't, it should be 1 if the ZIPersonId is not 0.

Comment: Your first attempt will effectively only return records which are in both LC and T since you are INNER JOINing CT to your LEFT JOINed T table. I am not sure what your "duplicate" criteria is (e.g. first name,last name, email, etc.) but I would start by pulling all INNER JOINed records from LC and T and then work on pulling from LC those which haven't made it across yet.

Comment: You should not edit your question, if you have a new one open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to replace the INNER JOIN with a LEFT JOIN:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ClientContacts
    (
        ClientUserID, PersonID, BusinessID, CompanyID, CompanyName, ContactName,
        ContactFirstName, ContactSurname, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, ContactMobile,
        ContactJobTitle, EmailBought, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3,
        County, Town, Country, CompanyTelephone, CompanyWebsite, Industry,
        DecisionMaker, PrimaryContact, ContactDisabled, CreationDate,
        BusinessListRecordID, IsPurchased
    )
    SELECT
        CT.ClientUserId,
        LC.ZIPersonId,
        LC.BusinessID,
        T.CompanyId,
        T.CompanyName,
        CONCAT(LC.FirstName, ' ', LC.Surname),
        LC.FirstName,
        LC.Surname,
        LC.EmailAddress,
        LC.Telephone AS ContactPhone,
        LC.Mobile AS ContactMobile,
        LC.JobTitle,
        T.EmailBought,
        T.AddressLine1,     
        T.AddressLine2,
        T.AddressLine3,
        T.County,
        T.Town,
        T.Country,
        T.Telephone,
        T.Website,
        T.Industry,
        LC.DecisionMaker,
        LC.PrimaryContact,
        LC.ContactDisabled,
        LC.CreationDate,
        LC.BusinessListRecordID,
        CASE LC.ZIPersonId WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM OldContacts LC
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Transaction] T ON LC.ZIPersonId = T.PersonId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CreditTransaction CT ON T.CreditTransactionId = CT.CreditTransactionId
```

This will select the OldContacts even when there are no Transactions or CreditTransaction.

To answer your new question:

```
CASE LC.ZIPersonId WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Should be

```
CASE T.PersonId WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Tried that before but it does not return the expected, check my edit. There are some columns missing

Comment: I will accept as this does answer my question, although it doesn't suit my requirements completely. That should be in another question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try an union first and then deselect all duplicates in the UNION of

```
 OLDCONTACTS
```

and

```
TRANSACTION.
```

Its hard to replicate your case, I would try something like this:

```
select the-cols-you-need from
   (
    select a.the-cols-you-need, a.distinct(foreign-key) from
        (
        select * from oldcontacts
        union all
        select * from transaction
        ) as a
   )
inner join CreditTransaction CT on a.transactionId = CT.transactionId
```